# Minor Problems with CKEditor

Tags: configuration, ckeditor

I have a minor problem with the configuration over the GUI of the CKEditor. In short words: It doesn't work! ;-)

I took a view into this, and it seems, it is a problem on my server with the url rewriting.

The settings GUI tries to load two files:

- http:///civicrm/admin/config.js?t=FB99
- http:///civicrm/admin/lang/de.js?t=FB99

I'm afraid, this are wrong urls, coming someway from url rewriting.

The maileditor works just fine, and gets the files from their "non rewritten" url:

- http:///sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/ckeditor/config.js?t=FACJ
- http:///sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/ckeditor/lang/de.js?t=FACJ

No real problem, because I may hack config.js by hand, instead using the GUI, but would be nice to have...

Bye

Comment: It would be great if you could investigate how those incorrect urls are being generated? Are you loading ckeditor in some nonstandard way?

Comment: I'm very sorry! I allready tried to find the place, where this urls are generated! But I didn't find anything! :-( I'm realy bad with JS!

I didn't change anything about the way ckeditor get's loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The CKEditor integration was re-written in CiviCRM 4.7. I recommend upgrading when that version is released, as it may solve your problem. You could verify that now by upgrading a test copy of your site to 4.7.beta.